# Ontology: Create class connections in an ontology

Tags: owl, ontology, rdflib

I have an ontology (a taxonomy, with classes only; no individuals) like this:

```
Owl:Thing
    Parts
        Jackfruit
        Jackfruit_flower 
        Grape
    Plant
        Jackfruit_tree
        Grapevine
```

I want to create a relation to connect the two classes *Parts* and *Plant* : *grows_in* which maps each part to a tree. Ultimately, I want to be able to write SparQL queries, for example: Which parts *grow_in* specific plants.

I read somewhere that using an annotation property is the best way to go about this. But, it seems like annotation properties don't work with reasoners / SparQL querying. It should be noted that the ontology I have is huge (>10,000 classes) and I'm using rdflib in python.

What's the best way I should go about creating relations between the classes (I already have the mappings with me, all that remains to be done is add in the relations) in order to be able to run SparQL queries?

Comment: [Reposted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50913763/1591669)

Answer (score 0):

What you should create is an Object Property: `grows_in`. Object Properties connecte `Individuals` to `Individuals`.

And moreover, this Object Property need to have `Plants` as `Domain` and `Parts` as `Range`.

Annotations properties are clearly not suited for it.

For example, a valable SPARQL Query will be :

```
PREFIX : <YOU_ONTOLOGY_URL>

SELECT * WHERE {
  ?parts :grows_in ?plan
}
```

EDIT: edited following comments

Comment: object properties "connect" individuals and not classes. Once you use an object property, the classes will become individuals - that's called punning. And for SPARQL it doesn't matter, it's for RDF, thus it doesn't distinguish between object properties or annotation properties.

Comment: Individuals are the illustration of Classes. So therefore, Object Properties connect Individuals but first Classes.

Comment: Strictly speaking the OWL specification of properties and the underlying description logic formalization of properties link pairs of individuals, not pairs of classes. I have written about this [here](http://henrietteharmse.com/2018/06/22/a-common-misconception-regarding-owl-properties/).